# Como passar dados do select para um array

Tags: c#, array

Como salvar os dados do select a baixo em um array

```
 SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco();
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select id, tamplete1, tamplete2 from usuarios ", conConexao1);
 SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
 if (dr1.HasRows == true)
 {
    if (dr1.Read())
    {
        id = int.Parse(dr1[0].ToString());
        templete1  = (dr1[1].ToString());
        templete2 = (dr1[2].ToString());
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para salvar os dados de uma linha de um SqlDataReader em um array use o método [`SqlDataReader.GetValues`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_GetValues_System_Object___) para popular o array de objetos com os valores da atual linha.

```
 SqlConnection conConexao1 = clsdb.AbreBanco();
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select id, tamplete1, tamplete2 from usuarios ", conConexao1);
 SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

 while (dr1.Read())
 {
     //Array para receber os dados
     Object[] array_dr1 = new Object[dr1.FieldCount];      

     //Preenche a array com os dados  
     dr1.GetValues(array_dr1);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser alterada a função `if`, por `while`, onde vai percorrer o reader.

```
while (dr1.Read())
{
    id = int.Parse(reader.GetOrdinal("id"));
    templete1  = (reader.GetOrdinal("tamplete1"));
    templete2 = (reader.GetOrdinal("tamplete2"));
}
```

Explicando o porquê:
Como diz a [Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read?view=netframework-4.8):

> O método `SqlDataReader.Read()` avança o `SqlDataReader` para o próximo registro e retorna `true` se houver mais linhas, caso contrário retorna `false`.